# Splunk rex: extracting repeating keys and values to a table

Tags: regex, splunk, splunk-query

I have some logs in Splunk for which I'm trying to extract a few values. My log entries look like this:

```
host-03.company.local:9011[read 3617, write 120 bytes] host-05.company.local:9011[read 370658827, write 177471 bytes] host-07.company.local:9011[read 99, write 96 bytes] host-07.company.local:9011[read 96, write 96 bytes] host-05.company.local:9011[read 120, write 120 bytes] host-05.company.local:9011[read 120, write 120 bytes] host-03.company.local:9015[read 42955, write 120 bytes] host-05.company.local:9015[read 3048879, write 86677386 bytes] host-02.company.local:7035[read 120, write 120 bytes] host-03.company.local:9015[read 120, write 120 bytes] host-05.company.local:9015[read 809077, write 120 bytes] host-02.company.local:7035[read 120, write 120 bytes] host-03.company.local:9015[read 120, write 120 bytes] host-05.company.local:9015[read 120, write 120 bytes] host-02.company.local:7035[read 120, write 120 bytes]
```

The pattern these log entries follow is `host:port[read xxx, write yyy bytes]`

There can be anywhere from 1 to about 20 host records in this log line.

What I'm hoping to do, in Splunk, is extract these fields to a table, such that the result looks like:

```
hostname                   readBytes WriteBytes
-----------------------------------------------
host-03.company.local:9011      3617        120
host-05.company.local:9011 370658827     177471
host-07.company.local:9011        99         96
host-05.company.local:9011       120        120
```

Logic here being that I'm extracting the `read` and `write` entries for each host, such that each one becomes a line in this table.

I've made some progress in extracting the hosts, with the rex:

```
index=myApplication <mySearch>
  | rex field=_raw "(?<hostsTmp>([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+:[0-9]+))"
  | table hostsTmp
```

However, even this result seems wrong, some of the results are just blank lines. In addition, the `hostsTemp` field doesn't seem to be a multi-variable field. mvcount(hostsTemp) returns nothing for each entry.

```
mvcount(hostsTmp)   len(hostsTmp)   hostsTmp
--------------------------------------------
    -                    -          host-05.company.local:9011
    -                    -          -
    -                    -          host-05.company.local:9011
    -                    -          -
    -                    -          host-05.company.local:9011
    -                    -          -
```

Note that I'm using the `-` character here to represent a lack of data in my table. Every other line is just completely blank, and the `mvcount` and `len` values for hostsTmp is always empty.

Relatively new to Splunk and not an expert in regex, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I suggest is to split each of your host's results into a separate event and then do a `rex` on each event.

This will take your full event and create a multi value field (named `ev`) for each of your hosts and their data.

```
| eval ev=split(raw,"]")
| mvexpand ev
```

Then, a simple `rex` can be used to extract the data.

```
| rex field=ev "^\s*(?<hostname>[^\[]+)\[read\s+(?<readBytes>\d+),\s+write\s+(?<writeBytes>\d+)\s+bytes"
```

And use `table` to format it appropriately.

```
| table hostname readBytes writeBytes
```

Here is an example showing it working. You will probably need to change the `split(raw` to point to the field in your own event, or use `_raw`.

```
| makeresults | eval raw="host-03.company.local:9011[read 3617, write 120 bytes] host-05.company.local:9011[read 370658827, write 177471 bytes] host-07.company.local:9011[read 99, write 96 bytes] host-07.company.local:9011[read 96, write 96 bytes] host-05.company.local:9011[read 120, write 120 bytes] host-05.company.local:9011[read 120, write 120 bytes] host-03.company.local:9015[read 42955, write 120 bytes] host-05.company.local:9015[read 3048879, write 86677386 bytes] host-02.company.local:7035[read 120, write 120 bytes] host-03.company.local:9015[read 120, write 120 bytes] host-05.company.local:9015[read 809077, write 120 bytes] host-02.company.local:7035[read 120, write 120 bytes] host-03.company.local:9015[read 120, write 120 bytes] host-05.company.local:9015[read 120, write 120 bytes] host-02.company.local:7035[read 120, write 120 bytes]"
| eval ev=split(raw,"]")
| mvexpand ev
| rex field=ev "^\s*(?<hostname>[^\[]+)\[read\s+(?<readBytes>\d+),\s+write\s+(?<writeBytes>\d+)\s+bytes"
| table hostname readBytes writeBytes
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for and worked perfectly. Thanks!